# Android application keeps crashing and I can't figure out why. Something with java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, list, sqlite

I'm using a DBHelper class with the following method

```
    public List<List<String>> getReservations (String username) {
        List<List<String>> reservations = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<String> row = new ArrayList();
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE username LIKE '" + username + "'", null);
        while(c1.moveToNext()) {
            row.add(c1.getString(1)); //parkingname
            row.add(c1.getString(2)); //date
            row.add(c1.getString(3)); //time
            reservations.add(row);
            row.clear();
        }
        c1.close();
        return reservations;
    }
```

My database is populated (100% sure of this, other methods work)

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Reservations(username VARCHAR, parkingname VARCHAR, date VARCHAR, timeslot VARCHAR);");`

Now whenever I try

```
        List<List<String>> values = database.getReservations(username);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myreservations);
        if(!values.isEmpty()) {
            String b = String.valueOf(values.size());
            List<String> lista = values.get(0); //crashes here
            String a = lista.get(0);
            text.setText(b + a);
        }
```

The application crashes with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myparking/com.example.myparking.MyReservations}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create row inside cursor cycle. When you call reservations.add(row), your row object is not copied into reservations, and when you call row.clear() - list cleared in both row and reservations.

```
    public List<List<String>> getReservations (String username) {
        List<List<String>> reservations = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE username LIKE '" + username + "'", null);
        while(c1.moveToNext()) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList();
            row.add(c1.getString(1)); //parkingname
            row.add(c1.getString(2)); //date
            row.add(c1.getString(3)); //time
            reservations.add(row);
        }
        c1.close();
        return reservations;
    }
```